# Playing random audio onClick doesn't reset when a new random audio file is created - Android

Tags: java, android, file, audio, random

Bit of an android programming noob here. Just trying to get my audio to stop playing and play the new random audio each time my imageButton is clicked. If you could help pinpoint my problem that would be great.

```
package com.shamu11.musesoundboard;

import java.util.Random;

//import com.shamu11.firstapp.MainActivity;
//import com.shamu11.firstapp.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton buttonOne;
private final int NUM_SOUND_FILES = 3;
private int mSndFilesMatt[] = new int[NUM_SOUND_FILES];
private Random rnd = new Random();
MediaPlayer matt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSndFilesMatt[0] = R.raw.fury;
    mSndFilesMatt[1] = R.raw.knights_of_cydonia;
    mSndFilesMatt[2] = R.raw.supremacy;

    buttonOne = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int sndToPlay = rnd.nextInt(NUM_SOUND_FILES);
            matt = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,     mSndFilesMatt[sndToPlay]);
            matt.seekTo(0);
            matt.start();

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int sndToPlay = rnd.nextInt(NUM_SOUND_FILES);
            matt.reset();
            matt = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,mSndFilesMatt[sndToPlay]);
            matt.seekTo(0);
            matt.start();
        }
```

Comment: This works for a bit, but after a few clicks (3 seconds left between each click) the audio begins to stutter and then mix in with the other audio.

Comment: i never worked with MediaPlayer before but i just wanna help try the new code after editing hope it works